# Is there a command in git for exporting working tree without archiving it?

Tags: git

I know there's `git archive`, but it creates archive. What I need is simply a working tree export with exclusion of the files marked with `export-ignore` in `.gitattributes`.

I could probably do it manually, or simply create archive with `git archive` and then extract it. But maybe there is and actual command for this?

Comment: The work-tree is not *in* the repository, so it can't possibly come out. The index contents *are* in there, but not in a usable form until written to the repository (via `git write-tree`, or of course `git commit`, which also writes the tree, then writes a commit that uses the tree). So you'll probably want to use `git archive` anyway. You can get the tree ID from `git write-tree` and archive that, as long as everything is ready to commit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this by piping the output to tar or unzip. As an example:

```
git archive --format=tar --prefix=junk/ HEAD | (tar xf -)
```

Will create a tar archive that contains the contents of the latest commit on the current branch, and extracts it in the /var/tmp/junk directory.

This is the first example in https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive

Comment: Hm... so probably this means there's no other way?.. But I'm on Windows here.

Comment: @jayarjo The edited answer should work in Windows by creating a folder named "junk" to the directory where you run it. I tested it with IE Virtual machine.

Comment: Did it survive tar part?